# subtracting numbers in fixed point format

Tags: fixed-point

I have two numbers in fixed point a(Q2n1,2m1) and b(Qn1,m1). to subtract these numbers a should have the same exponent size of b. now how to subtract them. I tried shifting a by m1 times to the right then a becomes (Q2n1,m1), but won't it affect the precision?

Is my approach correct?

regards, phani tej

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the approach is right. Nevertheless you need only a precision of only m1, which is enough, 2m1 precision is not required . And also you can only subtract if both the exponents are of the same size.